# python tkinter error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'"

Tags: python, tkinter

It's part of my python code. I tried to figure out but it's really tough.
the error appeared in "window.insert" Is there any way to fix this?

```
str = IntVar()
box = ttk.Combobox
values = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
box(self,width = 20,textvariable=str,state = "readonly",values = values).pack()

def pick():
    for i in range(0, str.get()):
        user_lotto = sample(range(1, 46), 7)
        user_lotto.sort()
        window.insert("current", "game{0} : {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7}".format(i+1, user_lotto[0], user_lotto[1], user_lotto[2], user_lotto[3], user_lotto[4], user_lotto[5], user_lotto[6]))
    window = Text(self, font=("Helvetica", 14)).pack()

Button(self, text="Go", font = ("Helvetica", 14),command=pick).place(x = 430, y = 75)
```

Comment: yeah. by making `window` object not being `NoneType`

Comment: Could you tell me more specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to store the `Text` object in `window`, but you actually store the return value of `pack`, which is None. Splitting the line like this should fix the error:

```py
window = Text(self, font=("Helvetica", 14))
window.pack()
```

Comment: both are same no problem with this

Comment: i think he should move window = Text(self, font=("Helvetica", 14)).pack() outside function and before the Button(XXXXXX) Creation